# mysql queries display the same value within multiple fields

Tags: mysql, sql

I not sure how to query out the same empID within this 5 fields of Emp_ID1 till Emp_ID5. Searching and count the same empID within those field of every rows.

```
------------------------------------------------------------
|Emp_ID1 | Emp_ID2 | Emp_ID3 | Emp_ID4 | Emp_ID5 | DATE
-------------------------------------------------------------
|   P1   |   P2    |    P3   |    P4   |    P5   | 2018-07-02
-------------------------------------------------------------   
|   P4   |   P3    |    P1   |    P8   |    P9   | 2018-07-03
-------------------------------------------------------------   
|   P5   |   P6    |    P4   |    P2   |    P1   | 2018-07-04
-------------------------------------------------------------   
|   P2   |   P3    |    P7   |    P8   |    P3   | 2018-07-04
-------------------------------------------------------------   
|   P5   |   P9    |    P3   |    P6   |    P1   | 2018-07-05
-------------------------------------------------------------
|   P5   |   P9    |    P3   |         |         | 2018-07-06
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

Date between 2018-07-02 and 2018-07-04

```
P1=3
P2=3
P3=4
P4=3
P5=2
P6=1
P7=1
P8=2
P9=1
```

Comment: You can unpivot the table using `UNION ALL` then `GROUP BY`. You should think about normalising your table though, as the table structure makes it very difficult to query the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `union` to merge data from different fields, and then use aggregation to get count for each employee id

```
select t.Emp_ID, count(*)
from(
  select Emp_ID1 Emp_ID  from your_table
  union all
  select Emp_ID2 Emp_ID from your_table
  union all
  select Emp_ID3 Emp_ID from your_table
  union all
  select Emp_ID4 Emp_ID from your_table
  union all
  select Emp_ID5 Emp_ID from your_table
) t
where t.Emp_ID is not null
group by t.Emp_ID
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f57812/4)

Comment: what kind of query is this `select Emp_ID1 Emp_ID  from your_table` exmplain the EMP_ID attribute why can be there

Comment: @user7367328 `Emp_ID` is just an alias (common name for different columns) to column and be represented using `AS` keyword `select Emp_ID1 AS Emp_ID `

Comment: i tried to put condition and added new attribute called datetime. Extra condition where datetime between 'Date1' and 'Date2' doesnt show accurate result. I put those datetime conditon in all query for the select inside the FROM

Comment: @user7367328 Run the inner query on its own. The result is how your table should look to begin with.

Comment: i added date at my current table and my query looks like `select t.Emp_ID, count(*)
from(
  select Emp_ID1 Emp_ID from your_table where create_date <= '2018-07-16'
  union all
  select Emp_ID2 Emp_ID from your_table where create_date <= '2018-07-16'
  union all
  select Emp_ID3 Emp_ID from your_table where create_date <= '2018-07-16'
  union all
  select Emp_ID4 Emp_ID from your_table where create_date <= '2018-07-16'
  union all
  select Emp_ID5 Emp_ID from your_table where create_date <= '2018-07-16'
) t
where t.Emp_ID is not null
group by t.Emp_ID`

Comment: @Strawberry there i update the above table. and how do i to make it shows correct result by adding the datetime condition between certain date